# Paypal Express Checkout for Digital Goods hangs when login is popup

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have been testing Paypal integration - on Sandbox - for a number of days and have found that, when the Paypal login is presented in a browser, everything is fine; However when the login environment changes to a popup/lightbox, the browser hangs and remains on 'loading' after a successful test payment has gone through.

I used PayPal integration wizard to generate the code and then amended it accordingly.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated as it's doing my head in!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue occur several times lately, as well as reported by a few of my customers.  While I can't provide a definitive solution, I have had success with one or more of the following:

1. Clear the browser cacher.  Shutdown and restart the browser.
2. Login to standard PayPal site, logout and restart browser.
3. Try a different browser to help identify whether there is something going on with that specific browser.
4. Switch between sandbox, live, and back to sandbox mode.  This may require a repeat of step  #1.
5. Contact Paypal customer support.

I typically resolve the problem before getting to #4, hopefully you will as well. Best of luck!